# Sybase only Last Value

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm looking for a solution for this case:

```
select pimpfung.idpatientklinik, pimpfung.idpatient_vaccination, pimpfung.datum                                                                                                                              
From ictq.pimpfung
order by   pimpfung.idpatientklinik
```

Output is:

```
idpatientklinik;idpatient_vaccination;datum
1;5500;01.02.2001
1;5567;05.09.2003
3;7766;22.08.2005
3;8899;25.09.2006
3;8900;29.09.2006
```

But I want the output like this:

```
1;5567;05.09.2003
3;8900;29.09.2006
```

(only the last values sort by "pimpfung.datum" desc)

How to do that ?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english ;-)

Comment: What is the datatype of the `datum` column? Is this a `(var)char`, `date`, `datetime`, something-else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from pimpfung p
where p.datum = (select max(p2.datum)
                 from pimpfung p2
                 where p2.idpatientklinik = p.idpatientklinik
                );
```

With an index on `(idpatientklinik, datum)` this is often the fastest approach.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22b2221167bc8e0ec87fe605e00d30e4) is a db<>fiddle (which uses SQL Server but this is all standard SQL).

Comment: So it seems to work not 100%... The values, that are not double are not visible with this anymore...

Comment: @Florian . . . I fixed the column names and added a db<>fiddle.  It does what you want.

Comment: I use this for another query, posted here in this thread and there it does not work. Can you please check this ? ...  It begins with "@Gordon Linoff: I now use this query:" What do you mean "with an index .... " ? What should I do ?